# Stored procedures in DeleteMethod of ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I created a stored procedure that deletes logs from a table (deleteLogs), and run it from the DeleteMethod I created for it. My problem is there is another stored procedure (recordLogs) inside that method that doesn't run at all.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="LogsDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLogs" UpdateMethod="UpdateLog" DeleteMethod="DeleteLog" TypeName="ServiceData">
 <DeleteParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="Id"/>
 </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

public void DeleteLog(int Id)
{
    getDataContext.deleteLogs(Id);  
    getDataContext.recordLogs(Id);      
}
```

However if I swap their order it work fine

```
public void DeleteLog(int Id)
{
    getDataContext.recordLogs(Id);
    getDataContext.deleteLogs(Id);        
}
```

Looks like as soon as an entry is deleted, it exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the recordLogs function relies on the values getting deleted by deleteLogs.

Also, think about wrapping both methods with TransactionScope():

```
public void DeleteLog(int Id)
{
    using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        getDataContext.recordLogs(Id);
        getDataContext.deleteLogs(Id);
        tran.Complete();
    }
}
```